# Any suggestion for To it, to it?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, word-usage

Can anyone suggest a meaning of "To it, to it!" not as intensifier, but on its own. The source is James Joyce's [Finnegans Wake](https://archive.org/stream/finneganswake00joycuoft/finneganswake00joycuoft_djvu.txt) 454.35. It comes after a wordplay with "Sanctus! Sanctus! Sanctus! and "Shanti shanti shanti" [Peace peace peace] the last line on TS Eliot's "Waste Land" but there Eliot also uses 'Tuit tuit tuit" a 16th century word meaning:
"to blame, reproach, taunt, upbraid," 1520s, twite, shortened form of Middle English atwite, from Old English ætwitan "to blame, reproach," from æt "at" (see at) + witan "to blame," from Proto-Germanic *witanan "to look after, guard, ascribe to, reproach" (source also of Old English wite, Old Saxon witi, Old Norse viti.

Nothing to do with the modern 'twit" term

> — There is some thing more. A word apparting and shall the  heart's
>   tone be silent. Engagements, I'll beseal you! Fare thee  well, fairy
>   well! All I can tell you is this, my sorellies. It's prayers  in
>   layers all the thumping time, begor, the young gloria's gang  voices
>   the old doxologers, in the suburrs of the heavenly gardens,  once we
>   shall have passed, after surceases, all serene through  neck and
>   necklike Derby and June to our snug eternal retribu-  tion's reward
>   (the scorchhouse). Shunt us! shunt us! shunt us!  If you want to be
>   felixed come and be parked. Sacred ease there!  The seanad and pobbel
>   queue's remainder. **To it, to it!** Seekit  headup!

Comment: I don't know that anyone can make sense of Finnegan's Wake.

Comment: @HotLicks *Finnegans Wake* doesn't have an apostrophe. Salvatross, I can't find the relevant passage in the version now linked; could you add it into your question, please? It's also not entirely clear whether you're actually asking about Joyce or Eliot.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Search for "454" and then look two lines above that number.